# redirect exact url to another url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

There are a bazillion examples online of doing redirects via apache's htaccess, but I can't find any example of redirecting a full URL match to another full URL.

For instance, I have an existing website at

```
https://example.com
```

How do I redirect some specific URLs for that domain to a different one:

```
https://example.com/login     -->  https://my.example.com/login
https://example.com/register  -->  https://my.example.com/register
```

For every other every other path on example.com I need to remain untouched so my site still works fine (i.e. `/blog` shouldn't redirect somewhere else).

Comment: Excuse me, you could implement this using pure html or mixing html and javascript (both without changing htaccess). Not your need? Best.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(login|register)/?$ http://my.example.com/$1 [L,R]
```

This will redirect `example.com/login` or `example.com/register` to `http://my.example.com/`

You can alternatively accomplish this using the `RedirectMatch` directive (if the newurl is on a diffrent webserver) :

```
RedirectMatch ^/(login|register)/?$ http://my.example.com/$1
```